# Could not set registry key when installing XAMPP on Windows Server

Tags: xampp

When installing XAMPP for Wordpress on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Entreprise,Service Pack 1 we got the following error:

[image]

The error says:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Could not set registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\xampp Install Dir REG_SZ

How to fix this?

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer:

[Probably](https://community.bitnami.com/t/issue-installing-xampp-in-window-7/43321), you should check that you don't have another installation of XAMPP in your system. If you have another installation, maybe you should uninstall it.

Comment: Please explain why your answer is a solution and include some quotes from your source to support your answer.